# Converting NSData To NSString While Reading Data from Buffer

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

I am doing stream read write operation .While reading if i am printing the read data which is NSData,its printing some values.But when I am using [NSString initwithData:] method to get the string text.I am getting null as the output.

Comment: Which encoding are you using for `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]` ? Are you sure that the data object you're passing is not nil?

Comment: The response data that I am getting  is <0700e4>.I am using NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: @AshleshaTripathy: `07 00 e4` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence (`e4` is the first byte of some incomplete UTF-8). What converted string to you expect?

Comment: @AshleshaTripathy: The `00` byte might also be problematic, because a NUL character in a string is often treated as delimiter. - In other words: you cannot just convert a "arbitrary sequence of bytes" to NSString. Can you tell us why the conversion is needed?

Comment: I am doing a stream operation using external accessory framework.After connecting a bluetooth device ,I am sending a text let say "hello" to the write stream .Now i want to read that text sent in the read stream from buffer.CAn you give a solution for that.